# JavaScript onload event

Tags: javascript, html

I need help understanding the following behavior. I don't want to change the code rather understand what is going on:

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Test</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="" id="mainForm">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
window.onload = function()
{
    alert("Load");

    mainForm.onsubmit = function(e)
    {
        alert("Submit");
    }
}
```

When I run test.html file, I get message 'Load' which makes sense. When I click on submit button I get message 'Submit' and 'Load'. Here is the question: How the function that display 'Submit' inside the anonymous function is called when I press the submit button? If I remove this code:

```
    mainForm.onsubmit = function(e)
    {
        alert("Submit");
    }
```

and place it outside of anonymous function then it will not be called (does not display message 'Sumbit'). Can anybody elaborate more in detail how/why this is working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: since your javascript comes before your form html, and you remove it from the `window.onload`, then `mainform`does not yet exist because your form hasnt been loaded, so the code doesn't do anything. when you put it inside of the `onload` it waits for the form to exist first

Comment: It behaves the same even if I place <script src="test.js"></script> right before the closing body tag.

Comment: id have to see a fiddle or something then.